# Как определить позицию элемента в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с английским алфавитом:

```
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
```

Хочу определить, какой у буквы `f` индекс в массиве. Есть ли функция с необходимым мне функционалом и можно ли это сделать не прогоняя весь массив через цикл?

Answer (score 6):

Используйте `indexOf`

```
alphabet.indexOf('f')
```

Кстати, `indexOf` есть и у строк.

```
// строка abc...
let str_alpha = String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(26).keys()].map(i=>i+97));
console.log(str_alpha.indexOf('f'));
// массив 'a', 'b', 'c'...
let arr_alpha = str_alpha.split('');
console.log(arr_alpaha);
```

Answer (score 2):

> функция с ... функционалом

зачет по русскому языку сдан.

---

```
var alphabetIndices = {
  ...
  f: 5,
  ...
};

var someLetter = 'f';
var index = alphabetIndices[someLetter]; // 5
```

Такое решение позволяет определять индекс буквы в алфавите, не заботясь о регистре:

```
var alphabetIndices = {
  ...
  f: 5, F: 5,
  ...
};
```

или использовать его для получения натурального номера буквы:

```
var alphabetOrdinals = {
  ...
  f: 6, F: 6,
  ...
};
```

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете создать объект вместо массива и в качестве значений для ключей использовать позицию буквы в алфавите? То есть так, как это бы произошло без лишних телодвижений в автоматическом порядке при инициализации массива?

Comment: @smellyshovel я предлагаю создать такой объект в дополнение к массиву

Comment: А какой от этого будет профит? Что-то я упускаю вашу мысль

Comment: @smellyshovel создать этот объект нужно один раз, там же где и массив. Поиск по нему делается оптимальным способом, внутренним поиском js движка по свойствам объекта.

Comment: А, то есть вся эта пляска только ради оптимизации поиска среди 26 значений?

Comment: @smellyshovel в вопросе просили - без циклов

Comment: А `indexOf`? Тем более, что в вопросе просили именно функцию (стандартную, видимо)

Comment: @smellyshovel Не понял про пляску. Кроме того, я написал в ответе, какие вижу возможности расширения использования такого подхода.

Comment: @smellyshovel Про `indexOf` и без меня нашлось кому написать.

Comment: "Про indexOf и без меня нашлось кому написать" - это все объясняет. Просто я сразу подумал, что вы даете именно непосредственно ответ на вопрос, а не предлагаете альтернативное решение, требующее использование отличного подхода от того, что желает использовать автора вопроса.

Comment: Я вам минусанул тут (вышло, что недопонимание. Хотя, будем объективны, вполне обоснованно). Теперь хочу голос убрать (все-таки разобрались), а SO не дает (видимо, какие-то нововведение, правки вашей требует).

Comment: @smellyshovel Ничего страшного. В споре рождается истина.

Answer (score 1):

еще вариант  через  indexOf():

```js
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

let res = alphabet.indexOf('v');
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

console.log(alphabet.findIndex(item => item === 'e'));
console.log(alphabet.findIndex(item => item === 'x'));
console.log(alphabet.findIndex(item => item === 'a'));
console.log(alphabet.findIndex(item => item === 'd'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Если без объявленного цикла, то можно так, но что под капотом во внутренних методах Array: split, join, toString, slice я не знаю, возможно в своих инструкциях и имеют циклы. Также можно создать и в последующем использовать, внутренний объект для записи искомых ключей.

```js
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
/*
// v.1 
var someLetter = 'z';
var result = (function(_first, _second){return [--_first.split(",").length, -(_second.split(",").length)]}).apply(null, ("," + alphabet.join() + ",").split("," +someLetter + ","));
 console.log(alphabet[result[0]]);
 console.log(alphabet.slice(result[0]).shift());
 console.log(alphabet.slice(result[1]).shift());
*/

// v.2.0.1
Array.prototype["_indexSide_"] = function(_markerName, _flag){
 return (function(_first, _second){
  return !!_second && !!_flag? // v.2.0.1  если _second при разделении равен undefined то метод вернёт несуществующий индекс 
//  return !!_flag? // v.2
   -(_second.split(",").length) // если _flag true то вернёт отрицательный порядковый индекс маркера с конца массива 
   :
   --_first.split(",").length; // если _flag не передан или false, метод возвращает порядковый индекс маркера от начала массива
 }).apply(null, (","  
  + this.toString() // v.2.0.1
//  + this.join() // v.2
  + ",").split("," +_markerName + ","))
}
 console.log(alphabet[alphabet._indexSide_("f")]);
 console.log(alphabet.slice(alphabet._indexSide_("a")).shift());
 console.log(alphabet.slice(alphabet._indexSide_("z", true)).shift());
 console.log(alphabet[alphabet._indexSide_("figvam")]);
```